# Prototype Ajax.Updater Eval Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have this sample page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Ajax Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_hello() {
    alert ("hello");    
}
alert ("Hello from JS");
</script>
</head>

<body>
This is the Ajax page.
<a href='#' onclick='ajax_hello();'>Click here to fire off JS function</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling it with this:

```
new Ajax.Updater($(element), page, { method: "get", evalScripts: true });
```

The alert is running, but the function is not registering (ajax_hello()).

Is there a way to get ajax to register a javascript function to the calling page?

Comment: How do you know it's not registering? Does the browser issue an error when you click the link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to the comment, I poked at the [documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater) and it appears that there are some special rules for Prototype when scripts are evaluated by the updater.  The scripts can be anywhere in the response, **but** you need to assign any function definitions to a global variable to make them available to your page.

> About evalScripts and defining
>   functions If you use evalScripts:
>   true, any  block will be
>   evaluated. This does not mean it will
>   get included in the page: they won't.
>   Their content will simply be passed to
>   the native eval() function. There are
>   two consequences to this:
>
> The local scope will be that of
>   Prototype's internal processing
>   function. Anything in your script
>   declared with var will be discarded
>   momentarily after evaluation, and at
>   any rate will be invisible to the
>   remainder of the page scripts. If you
>   define functions in there, you need to
>   actually create them, otherwise they
>   won't be accessible to the remainder
>   of the page scripts. That is, the
>   following code won't work:
>
> ```
> // This kind of script won't work if processed by Ajax.Updater:
> function coolFunc() {
>     // Amazing stuff!
> }
> ```
>
> You
>   will need to use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> // This kind of script WILL work if processed by Ajax.Updater:
> coolFunc = function() {
>    // Amazing stuff!
> }
> ```

Comment: Then explain "the alert is running."

Comment: @Jonathan -- it appears that it's handled differently, but there are some special considerations.  I've updated.

Comment: makes sense since this in effect overrides any previous functions named coolFunc(). Thanks!